# How to display specified text of buttons in the same textView in sequence when different buttons are clicked in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, button, textview, onclick, onclicklistener

I am having a problem in Android Studio. I have got two different buttons and a textView. The effect that I want is as follows:

CASE 1: When bt1 is clicked, "A" is displayed in textView. When the bt2 is clicked, "G" is added in textView so the textView displays "AG".

CASE 2: When bt1 is clicked, "A" is displayed in textView. When bt1 is clicked again, it disappears and the textView is empty.

CASE 3: When CASE 1  is done, as bt1 is clicked, "A" is removed so that textView displays"G".

Your help in altering my code is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Main Activity code:

```
public class keyboard extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn1,btn2,btn3;
TextView text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_keyboard);
    text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
    btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt1);
    btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt2);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v){
            text.setText("A");
            text.setVisibility(text.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v){
            text.setText(text.getText() + "G");
            text.setVisibility(text.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go..

```
public class Keyboard extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn1, btn2;
    TextView text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_keyboard);
        text = findViewById(R.id.txt);
        btn1 = findViewById(R.id.bt1);
        btn2 = findViewById(R.id.bt2);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (text.getText().equals("A")) {
                    text.setText("");
                    text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else if (text.getText().equals("AG")) {
                    text.setText("G");
                } else {
                    text.setText("A");
                }
            }
        });

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                text.setText(String.format("%sG", text.getText()));
            }
        });
    }
}
```